# Connecting points in an annulus with horizontal and vertical segments

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, connectedness, path-connected

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 1.34

[image]

I guess the answer is to do with Eg 1.13:

[image]

---

For $D[0,1]$ or $D[0,3]$, maximum is 2.

For $D \cdot [0,1]$ or $D \cdot [0,3]$, maximum is 3, achieved when the points are on a line passing through 0. Edit: Upon reflection, I think maximum is 5

For $D[0,3] \setminus D[0,2]$, maximum is I guess 5, achieved when, but not only when, the points are on a line passing through 0 and close to $D[0,3]$?

If right, then what's the justification please?

If wrong, why and how else can I approach this please?

---

Asked here but there are no posted answers: [Find the maximum number of horizontal and vertical segments in $G$ needed to connect two points of $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571313/)

Related:

[Prove that $A_{r,s}$ $=[z\in \mathbb C : r<|z-z_0|<s ]$ is path connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492542/)
[An annulus in $\mathbb R^2$ is path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/)

Comment: The MAXIMUM number is unlimited.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Okay why $\infty$ please? I'm trying to see a pattern here: if you delete a point then max is 3 and then if you delete a concentric circle with radius 0.00001 then max is perhaps 5 and then if the deleted concentric circle has a certain large enough radius than the max is $\infty$. Is the threshold perhaps that the deleted concentric circle has a radius greater than the difference of the two radii?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Why would it be unlimited? There certainly is a closed zig-zag made of finitely many h/v segments contained within that annulus, then for any two points one only needs to "connect" them to that.

Comment: @dxiv Wait...it's a finite number, but I think the claim is that that finite number isn't necessarily...bounded? Might be mixing up terms here. $\infty$ is just something I (not WilliamElliot) used to try to sound precise or vacuous. I guess I was wrong and that $\infty$ is instead applicable to maximum number of line segments connecting any 2 points in $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$

Comment: @BCLC That number is certainly bounded. The zig-zag itself is independent of the choice of the two points, and each of the two points can reach the zig-zag with (at most) one segment.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, what's the bound please?

Comment: @BCLC Too long for a comment, posted as an answer. Note the last "*but*" however.

Answer (score 2):

Exercise 1.34 is clearly meant to be a little brain teaser. It has nothing to do with complex analysis or topology.

Choose an $h\in\>\bigl]2,{3\over\sqrt{2}}\bigr[\>$, e.g., $h:=2.06$, and draw the four lines $x=\pm h$, $y=\pm h$. Their four points of intersection are lying in the interior of the annulus $\Omega$. Every point in $\Omega$  can be joined within $\Omega$ to one of these lines by a horizontal or vertical segment. It follows that any two points in $\Omega$ can be joined with a chain of $\leq5$ horizontal or vertical segments $\sigma_i\subset\Omega$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian Blatter! Is this some standard topology thing, and may you please provide relevant reading material please?

Comment: (+1) `clearly meant to be a little brain teaser` Indeed. If the circles has radii $3,4$ (or $13,14$ for that matter), the problem would have suddenly become a lot more complicated.

Comment: Christian Blatter, @dxiv Ok then how does one come up with this answer please? Edit: Oh I saw dxiv's edit. Do you agree Christian Blatter?

Answer (score 1):

(*Following up on a previous comment, posting as an answer for the sake of the pic*.)

It is possible to draw a $12$-side polygon with only h/v sides contained within the given annulus, and each of the two points can reach it with (at most) one segment. Therefore an upper bound to the answer is $\,8\,$, but this alone doesn't prove that it's the *lowest* upper bound i.e. *the* maximum.

[image]

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The minimum is in fact $\,5\,$, as shown in [Christian Blatter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2867833/291201).

A related, more general question, would be what is the required number of segments to connect any two points in an annulus by arbitrary line segments, without restricting them to be horizontal or vertical, only. A similar argument could show that the magic number is $\,\lfloor n/2 \rfloor +3\,$ where $\,n\,$ is the minimum integer such that a regular $n$-gon can be strictly entirely inside the annulus.

Since the ratio between of the radii of the inscribed vs. circumscribed circle to a regular $n$-gon is $\,r / R = \cos \pi/n\,$, it follows that for $\,n=4\,$ an annulus with $\,1/2 \le r/R \lt 1 / \sqrt{2}\,$ would require $\,\lfloor 4/2\rfloor + 3=5\,$ segments (which is the answer here because $2/3 \in \left[1/2, 1/\sqrt{2}\right)\,$ indeed), for $\,n=5\,$ an annulus with $\,1 / \sqrt{2} \le r/R \lt (1+\sqrt{5})/4\,$ would also require $\,5\,$ segments (but those would no longer be just horizontal and vertical), for $\,n=6\,$ an annulus with $\,(1+\sqrt{5})/4 \le r/R \lt \sqrt{3} / 2\,$ would require $\,6\,$ segments etc.

Comment: Thanks dxiv! I won't accept answer in case someone has an idea for supremum

Comment: @BCLC Thanks. Fixed and clarified the last line now. And, yes, it's not an answer to what the maximum is, but the context of the comment I was following up on was just claiming that it's bounded for sure.

Comment: There is a minimum.  There is no maximum because the zigs and zags can be made smaller and smaller, requiring more and more of them.

Comment: dxiv, cross-examine @WilliamElliot ?

Comment: dxiv, @WilliamElliot, do you concur with Christian Blatter?

Comment: @WilliamElliot You are right about that, but I took the original question "*find the maximum number* ***needed*** *to connect*" to mean the ***minimum*** number of segments that are required to connect any two ***arbitrary*** points. If you remove the "*needed*" part from the question (or if you interpret it differently), then yes you can zig-zag forever between two points.

Comment: Just as you observed @dxiv, the question was wrongly stated.  In addition it ambigously stated for two points which could also mean for any two points.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Why is it wrongly stated when it says needed?